# Violating the Device and Network Abuse policy when add YouTube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-play, google-play-services, android-youtube-api

My application has been removed from google play and I do not understand the problem or how to solve it. I use the YouTube API to display videos and follow all the guidelines to do so.

First, an email came with the text: "Your app shouldn't access or use the service or API in a manner that violates its terms of service. For example, your app shouldn't download, monetize, or access YouTube videos in a way that violates the YouTube Terms of Service. "

Upon appeal, I received the following response: "For example, your app currently contains copyrighted contents from YouTube without consent from the contents' owners. You can refer to the attached screenshot for additional information."

The screenshot is just one of the videos in my application. But wait, I have added everything according to the YouTube guidelines, and there is also a direct quote from the rules.

> License to YouTube
>
> By providing Content to the Service, you grant to YouTube a worldwide,
> non-exclusive, royalty-free, transferable, sublicensable license to
> use that Content (including to reproduce, distribute, modify, display
> and perform it) for the purpose of operating, promoting, improving the
> Service.
>
> License to Other Users
>
> You also grant each other user of the Service a worldwide,
> non-exclusive, royalty-free license to access your Content through the
> Service, and to use that Content (including to reproduce, distribute,
> modify, display, and perform it) only as enabled by a feature of the
> Service.

Which means that if embedding is enabled by the author of the channel, then I can embed his videos in my application. So what's the problem then?

Has anyone encountered this? I use the official YouTube player, maybe I didn't notice something and now any embedding is prohibited? But the rules say you can!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: It is about implementations of YouTube API